# Error occured when trying to configure IIS Express for project. redirection.config cannot read file due to insufficient permision

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, xamarin, iis-express-10

I'm trying to debug IIS Express as I was creating a web service to connect my application to the database. Unfortunately, an error box pop out shows:

> The following error occur when try to configure IIS Express for project. Filename:redirection.config
>   Error:Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions.

Some told me to uncheck the read-only properties at the IISExpress folder that located in Documents, but whenever I did this, the folder keeps revert to read-only properties back. Please help me.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I'm running Windows Home. I really want to get back to .NET development but not with these problems!

Answer (score 2):

One drive might also be the cause of it. I experience the same issue when I closed one drive and stopped syncing but the problem was solved when I resumed it.